# Copy to clipboard HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a small site to generate amazon affiliate link using asin
I used a small script to generate the URL but I'm looking to copy the output in the clipboard directly.

I looked around without finding a suitable solution for my problem.

Here is the script I'm using to generate the URL.

The HTML part is just an input and a button.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput");
        let url = document.querySelector("#url");
        
        url.innerHTML = "https://www.amazon.it/dp/" + userInput.value + "/ref=nosim?tag=altpe-21";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Probably using a library like e.g. https://clipboardjs.com would fit your needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Clipboard` API in the `navigator` for this purpose.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput");
        let url = document.querySelector("#url");
        
        let output = "https://www.amazon.it/dp/" + userInput.value + "/ref=nosim?tag=altpe-21";
        url.innerHTML = output;

        navigator.permissions.query({name: "clipboard-write"}).then(result => {
            if (result.state == "granted" || result.state == "prompt") {
                 navigator.clipboard.writeText(output);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution you'll have to create another function once the link is already created and up in the website.

The new function will use the `document.getElementById()` function and the `.select()` method

example and implementation can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution:

```
/* Get the text field */
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
    
/* Select the text field */
copyText.select();
copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
    
/* Copy the text inside the text field */
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
    
/* Alert the copied text */
alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
```